# jQuery's CSS property

Tags: jquery, css

This may be a really stupid question, but I'm new to jQuery and am not understanding its css property like I thought I was,

It's blowing my mind that

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
```

and

```
$("#cloud").css({
    "top" :  + 100 + "px",  
    "left" : "100px"});
```

work.

But that when I try and reuse that same idea here,

```
$("cloud").css({
    "-webkit-transform" : "rotate(30deg)"});
```

It doesn't work. It seems as though I am using the exact same syntax.

I apologize for the stupid question.

~Austin

Comment: Is that a typo or are you actually missing the # in your selector?

Comment: Funny how the smallest, most obvious mistakes can be the ones that make you tear out your hair in frustration.

Comment: Wow. Somebody should revoke my rights to publish. I spent an hour troubleshooting before I posted this up here. Maybe I should copy and paste next time. :P

Answer (score 2):

It actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/nzmfW/
but you messed up the selector:

```
$("cloud").css({"-webkit-transform" : "rotate(30deg)"});
```

should probably be :

```
$("#cloud").css({"-webkit-transform" : "rotate(30deg)"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#cloud").css({"-webkit-transform" : "rotate(30deg)"});
```

You are missing a `#` before the `id` in the selector in the second line.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GyfSa/)</kbd>.